# Need to add a column to a pd.df with values from a function

Tags: pandas, for-loop, python-3.6

My Dataframe looks like this:

```
In [325]: TYVOL.tail()
Out[325]: 
               Close
Date                
2017-11-24  0.027705
2017-11-27  0.029335
2017-11-28  0.029335
2017-11-29  0.029498
2017-11-30  0.031454
```

tried this:

```
TYVOL['pb'] = [my_probability_gamma(TYVOL.Close[date],shape0,shape1,shape2,scale0,
               scale1,scale2,pbv0,pbv1,pbv2,date) for date in TYVOL.index]
```

which throws a KeyError: Timestamp

Anything obvious i am doing wrong? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your approach is working for me, can you show which line is throwing the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need `loc`:

```
TYVOL['pb'] = [my_probability_gamma(TYVOL.loc[date, 'Close'],shape0,shape1,shape2,scale0,
               scale1,scale2,pbv0,pbv1,pbv2,date) for date in TYVOL.index]
```

Or [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) and instead `date` use `x.name`:

```
f = lambda x: my_probability_gamma(x['Close'],shape0,shape1,shape2,
                                   scale0, scale1,scale2,pbv0,pbv1,pbv2,x.name)
TYVOL['pb'] = TYVOL.apply(f, axis=1)
```

Or use [`iteritems`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iteritems.html):

```
TYVOL['pb'] = [my_probability_gamma(c,shape0,shape1,shape2,scale0,
               scale1,scale2,pbv0,pbv1,pbv2,d) for d, c in TYVOL['Close'].iteritems()]
```

Test:

```
def my_probability_gamma(x,y,z):
    return (x,y,z)
```

---

```
shape0 = 1

TYVOL['pb'] = [my_probability_gamma(TYVOL.loc[date, 'Close'],shape0,date) for date in TYVOL.index]
print (TYVOL)
               Close                                  pb
Date                                                    
2017-11-24  0.027705  (0.027705, 1, 2017-11-24 00:00:00)
2017-11-27  0.029335  (0.029335, 1, 2017-11-27 00:00:00)
2017-11-28  0.029335  (0.029335, 1, 2017-11-28 00:00:00)
2017-11-29  0.029498  (0.029498, 1, 2017-11-29 00:00:00)
2017-11-30  0.031454  (0.031454, 1, 2017-11-30 00:00:00)
```

---

```
shape0 = 1
 f = lambda x: my_probability_gamma(x['Close'],shape0,x.name)
TYVOL['pb'] = TYVOL.apply(f, axis=1)
print (TYVOL)
               Close                                            pb
Date                                                              
2017-11-24  0.027705  (0.027705, 1, 2017-11-24T00:00:00.000000000)
2017-11-27  0.029335  (0.029335, 1, 2017-11-27T00:00:00.000000000)
2017-11-28  0.029335  (0.029335, 1, 2017-11-28T00:00:00.000000000)
2017-11-29  0.029498  (0.029498, 1, 2017-11-29T00:00:00.000000000)
2017-11-30  0.031454  (0.031454, 1, 2017-11-30T00:00:00.000000000)
```

---

```
TYVOL['pb'] = [my_probability_gamma(c,shape0,d) for d, c in TYVOL['Close'].iteritems()]
print (TYVOL)
               Close                                              pb
Date                                                                
2017-11-24  0.027705              (0.027705, 1, 2017-11-24 00:00:00)
2017-11-27  0.029335  (0.029335000000000003, 1, 2017-11-27 00:00:00)
2017-11-28  0.029335  (0.029335000000000003, 1, 2017-11-28 00:00:00)
2017-11-29  0.029498  (0.029498000000000003, 1, 2017-11-29 00:00:00)
2017-11-30  0.031454              (0.031454, 1, 2017-11-30 00:00:00)
```

Comment: good ideas but sadly still throwing the same error with both suggestions

Comment: I test it and it working nice, I add my tests to answer.

Comment: i add another solution, please check it.

Comment: still getting the same annoying error jezrael. am grateful for your suggestions though.

Comment: There has to be some data problem, is possible share data? `TYVOL.to_pickle('pkl1.pkl')` ?

Comment: For me it working perfectly, all 3 solutions. Maybe problem in pandas version or in function.

Comment: Idea - What is your pandas version?

Comment: Pandas 0.21.0, Python 3.6.3, numpy 1.13.3

Comment: this feels like a Pandas bug. Found that it shows the error at a few unspecific dates. KeyError: Timestamp('2015-10-12 00:00:00')
while all dates from 2015-01-01 work.... weird

Comment: So it doest work with my sample function too? Or with yoiur real function only?

Comment: And I have idea, is possible see your real function `my_probability_gamma` for test?

Comment: All good now jezreal. Found the problem. The function uses another dataset where dates were missing. Grateful for your help!

Comment: Supeeer, this is good news, because I have no other idea ;) Nice weekend!